# High resolution figure when using the axes method for subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, subplot

When creating a figure using **plt.figure**, one can set its size and resolution in the following way:

```
plt.figure(num=1, figsize=(6, 4), dpi=150)
```

How can this be obtained when creating a figure using the following code?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

I've tried the code bellow but I get the error
*TypeError: 'Figure' object is not callable*

```
ax.figure(num=1, figsize=(6, 4), dpi=150)
```

Thanks for your help and suggestions!

Comment: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=150)`? using **fig_kw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plt.subplots()` supports all the keyword parameters of `plt.figure()`, so to change the resolution, just do:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=150)
```

Take a look at the docs:

- https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html

EDIT: The reason your code isn't working is because `ax.figure` is a Figure object, not a function. This is why it's "not callable."